# React/redux using post request to update database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to update my database using react/redux and I am at a loss as to how. From what I understand it can be done using a fetch post request. I'm trying to do this in my action creators but i think my overall understanding of the syntax of a post request is lacking.

If i could get an example of the proper way to use fetch to use a post request i'd appreciate it, or even a link to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I took the fetch example from the Mozilla [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```
export function postDataSuccess(response) {
  return {
    type: 'POST_SOMETHING',
    response
  };
}

export function postData(url, data) {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch(url, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // must match 'Content-Type' header
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, same-origin, *omit
    headers: {
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer', // *client, no-referrer
  })
  .then(response => dispatch( postDataSuccess(response.json()) ));
 }
}
```

Then in your code you can use postData whenever you need to make the action, and in your reducers to listen for 'POST_SOMETHING' action.